# List item doesn't update

Tags: c#, winforms

Well, i have a simple List of classes which might get updated during run-time the problem is that when i set a property it doesn't update in the List.

Code:

```
class Foo
{
    public List<Link> Link => new List<Link>();

    public Foo()
    {
        //... Code that adds items to the list.
        var addr = Link.Find(_ => _.Valid).Use().Address;
        //here if i break and look at the Link list it must contain an item with Valid = false, yet it doesn't
    }
}

public class Link
{
    public Uri Address { get; set; }
    public bool Valid = true;

    public Link Use()
    {
        Valid = false;
        return  this;
    }
}
```

i know that it must update because i am using a reference of that item in the list, yet for some unknown reason it doesn't.

Comment: You will have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  I would look at using a BindingList<T> instead of a List<T> as well.  Your `Use` function isn't a property.

Comment: Is this WPF, or UWP, or winforms, or what? If it's any kind of XAML, use `ObservableCollection<T>`, not `List<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you are getting the value of `Link` property new list instance is created and returned. You should initialize property only once and return the same instance of the list when you are getting property value:

```
public List<Link> Link { get; } = new List<Link>();
```

---

Why your code do not work? Think about what happens when you add two items this way and perform a search:

```
Link.Add(new Link());
Link.Add(new Link());
Link.Find(...)
```

1. You are calling getter of `Link` property which creates new instance of the list and returns that empty instance.
2. You are adding first `Link` object to the instance of the list which you are received in step #1.
3. You are calling getter of `Link` property again, which creates new instance of the list (yes, another instance) and returns that new instance (empty list).
4. You are adding second `Link` object to the new empty list return on step #3.
5. You are calling getter of `Link` property which creates third instance of the list (again, empty) and returns that instance.
6. You are calling `Find` method of the empty list returned on step #5.

Comment: oh :D, that's a bummer